# MYSQL-Matching values with in same column values multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a table named as Team where table contain 3 column (ID,Team,Task). Its datatypes are `(INT,VARCHAR(255),INT)`. Below you will find a sample table where I would like to perform the query on column team.

```
   -----------------------------
   |ID|        Team      |Task |
   -----------------------------
   |1 |team1,team2,team5 |23   |
   |2 |team3,team2       |34   |
   |3 |team1,team5,team3 |45   |
   |4 |team2             |2    |
   |5 |team1,team3       |65   |
   |6 |team2,team5       |4    |
   |7 |team1             |34   |
   |8 |team5             |67   |
   -----------------------------
```

My question is that i like to check whether value in column team is subset of any of the value in same column team (It should not check with it own value in the column team), if that value comes out to be true then i would like to delete that row which has that value.It should run for all values of column team.

OUTPUT table will be like this

```
   ---------------------------
   |ID|    Team          |Task|
   ---------------------------
   |1 |team1,team2,team5 |23  |
   |2 |team3,team2       |34  |
   |3 |team1,team5,team3 |45  |
   ----------------------------
```

As you can see in team5 is subset of `{team2,team5},{team1,team5,team3} and {team1,team2,team5}`, Same with `team1 ,{team2,team5} ,{team1,team3}, team2` they will also get removed because they are subset of some value in column team.

If there is any other approach to do this then do tell me. In initial Table i used group_concat function on it to get all values related to particular ID.

Comment: Simple. See normalization

Comment: @Strawberry : please guide me

Comment: @Strawberry: if somehow i do Normalization then again i will reach to the same situation where i have applied group_concat(). That's why i got all Team value combined for particular ID after that i have to perform such subset operation on this

Comment: To my mind, there is no problem in MySQL for which GROUP_CONCAT is (part of) the solution. So, I suggest you start again, with the 'inital table', whatever that is.